# Dead code warning in Eclipse - is this a bug in Eclipse? Or me overlooking something obvious?

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings, dead-code

With this (simplified) code example Eclipse (Kepler SR2) gives a warning for the innermost if-statement `(if (con != null))`, *dead code*.

```
public class DbManager {
    public String getSingleString(String query) throws SQLException {
        DbManager dbmgr = new DbManager();
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            con = dbmgr.getConnection("user", "pwd", URL);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            if (con != null) {
                PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
                ResultSet rset = null;
                pstmt = con.prepareStatement(query.toString());
                rset = pstmt.executeQuery();
                if (rset != null && rset.next()) {
                    return (rset.getString(1));
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Typically the database connection defined on the line after the try will create a connection and then the offending if-statement will be true. Is the warning about dead code really correct?

Comment: With the code given here, yes it is. The only thing that can result in a `SQLException` is the assignment. If the assignment fails `con` is always `null`.

Comment: The warning is correct. You initialize with null and if the catch block is executed, the try block can't be initialize your `con`.

Comment: con can only be null in the catch-block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the connection is successfully created, then that catch statement will never be called so it is dead code, try rearranging it to:

```
try {
    con = dbmgr.getConnection("user", "pwd", URL);
    //if (con != null) { <-- not required because of the try and catch
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    ResultSet rset = null;
    pstmt = con.prepareStatement(query.toString());
    rset = pstmt.executeQuery();
    if (rset != null && rset.next()) {
        return (rset.getString(1));
    }
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 12):

If `dbmgr.getConnection("user", "pwd", URL);` returns an exception, then `con` will never get assigned a non-null reference.

You initialized `con` with null. So when an exception will be thrown and your code will reach the catch, `con` will be null. That is why that check `(con != null)` does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I realised the problem after running the code a couple of times and bumping into some problems: one } was missing after the catch. It should be:

```
try {
    con = dbmgr.getConnection("cap_x1", "test");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
    if (con != null) {
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        ResultSet rset = null;
```

etc. Thank you for your feedback.